# Smooth continuous animation without jumps

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I am struggling with this for 3 days now, would appreciate your help!
I am trying to make simple continuous animation on y axis.

The problem is that the animation is not smooth!!!
It has jumps and hiccups.
It is hard to see in the beginning, but once you see it, you can't get rid of it.

Here is an example:

http://dl.dropbox.com/u/19570262/movementTest.swf

Here is the source file:

http://dl.dropbox.com/u/19570262/movementTest.fla

This particular code is pretty simple:

```
import flash.events.Event;

addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, moveRoad);

var deltaY:Number = 0;

function moveRoad(event:Event):void
{
    deltaY = (deltaY < stage.stageHeight) ? deltaY + 5  : 0;
    road1.y = deltaY;
    road2.y = deltaY - road1.height
}
```

But trust me until now I tried like 20 different  solutions which also didn't work.
The solutions I tried until now:

- animate by setInterval()
- animate by getTime()
- animate bitmaps
- animate by copyPixels

The only one that worked was using stage3D and Starling! But I can't use it for my project.
Anyone?

Comment: Just a guess: It could be, becuase you set deltaY to 0 when it is too high. Try this:

deltaY = (deltaY + 5) % stage.stageHeight

Comment: Hi Nico, tried it. This is not the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You could try using TweenLite and BlitMask

http://www.greensock.com/blitmask/

Comment: This might be an issue with your system/flash player plugin.

Comment: The problem exists on all systems, all flash players.